# VB6 File IO questions (FreeFile, File Number, and Dir command)

Tags: file-io, vb6

I'm converting an old VB6 app that's been chugging along for years, but has a server name hard-coded into it.  We want to convert it to a C# app, and I'm doing OK reading most of the VB6 code, except I'm not 100% sure I'm reading the code right when it comes to some basic File IO operations.

Several lines of code call the FreeFile function.  I see that VB.NET has the function, and I've [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.freefile%28VS.80%29.aspx) but it's still not making sense to me.

> **Remarks**
>
> Use FreeFile to supply a file number that is not already in use.

Question 1: All of my searching is not telling me what a "file number" is or what it's used for.  Is this some way of referring to a file, but not by file name?

Question 2: I'm also not sure about the Dir function.  To me it looks like it's equivalent to System.IO.File.Exists(), is that right?

Example code:

```
If Not Dir(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\path.txt") = "path.txt" Then
   End
Else
   iFile = FreeFile
   FileOpen(iFile, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\path.txt", OpenMode.Input)
   Input(iFile, lsDataIn)
   FileClose()
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FreeFile` is not needed in C#, since it has been completely abstracted away.  Just open your files in C# using the standard File I/O.

As far as `Dir` function goes, it was very versatile in VB6 and did a number of things.  In this context, yes, you are correct, it can be replaced with `File.Exists`.

So your code in C# could look like this:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("path.txt"))
    Application.Exit();
else
    string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you and +1...  I understand I could use regular I/O operations on the file.  I modified my question slightly, to clarify what I'm asking and you answered the second question perfectly.  Are you able to explain what a *File Number* is and what it was used for? I'm very comfortable with processing files in .NET, but I'm a little more nervous just assuming I understand older code.  It would be far too easy to mis-read older code and do something completely different in my new code thinking I was performing the same task.

Comment: In (ancient) BASIC programming, when you opened a file, you supplied a number (1, 2, 3, etc) so that you could have multiple files open at the same time and refer to them by number. FreeFile gave you a number you could safely use to open your next file.

Comment: I think I finally got that - it *looks* like it's almost used like a variable name to refer to the file.  Mayby not exactly, but conceptually, it looks similar.  Thanks, @Joel Spolsky for taking the time!

Comment: remember that old versions of basic didn't really have variables - certainly not file reference pointers. They probably had A-Z (26 numeric variables) and A$ and B$ (two strings up to 16 characters each).